# Why am I getting list index out of bounds (1) error?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe7, firedac

I am getting this error message:

> List index out of bounds (1)

when trying to select information from my database. I am using Delphi XE7, MySQL 6.2, FDConnection and FDQuery. My code is:

```
Procedure TAppointmentForm.GetTreatPrice;
Begin
  TreatPriceQuery.SQL.Text:= 'Select Cost from Treatment where TreatName = '+quotedstr(Treatment)+'';
  TreatPriceQuery.Open;
  TreatPrice:= TreatPriceQuery.FieldByName('Cost').AsInteger;
End;
```

I am using a CheckBoxList to get `Treatment`. My code for this is:

```
Procedure TAppointmentForm.GetAppCost;
Var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  for Count := 0 to (Count1-1) do
    Begin
      if TreatmentCheckListBox.State[Count] = cbChecked then
        Begin
          Treatment:= TreatmentCheckListBox.Items.Strings[Count];
          GetTreatPrice;
          AppCost:= AppCost + TreatPrice;
        End
      Else
        AppCost:= AppCost;
    End;
end;
```

Comment: In the loop in `GetAppCost()`, where is `Count1` coming from, and what is being assigned to it?  The loop need to use the value from `TreatmentCheckListBox.Items.Count`, if it is not already doing so.

Comment: Also, why are you using a global/member variable to pass the `Treament` and `TreatPrice` values around?  Why not just give `GetTreatPrice()` an input parameter and a return value?

Comment: `Count1` is the variable I used to add them to the list to start with

Comment: Then `Count1` is likely out of sync with the actual `Items.Count`.  You should use the actual `Items.Count` in your loop instead.  Also `AppCost:= AppCost` is redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is overly complex. You can use the `Checked` property of the `TCheckListBox`, and drop the `Strings` totally when accessing the items in the content (`Strings` is the default property of `Items`). Also, you should use the `Count` of `Items` in your loop.

```
Procedure TAppointmentForm.GetAppCost;
Var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  for Idx := 0 to TreatmentCheckListBox.Items.Count - 1 do
  Begin
    if TreatmentCheckListBox.Checked[Idx] then
    Begin
      Treatment:= TreatmentCheckListBox.Items[Idx];
      GetTreatPrice;
      AppCost:= AppCost + TreatPrice;
    End;
  // The next two lines are a non operation. Assigning a
  // variable to itself does nothing. Remove them entirely
 // Else
 //  AppCost:= AppCost;
    End;
end;
```

Also, stop concatenating text for your SQL, and use parameterized queries instead, both for efficiency and for protection against SQL injection.

```
Procedure TAppointmentForm.GetTreatPrice;
Begin
  TreatPriceQuery.SQL.Text:= 'Select Cost from Treatment where TreatName = :TreatName';
  TreatPriceQuery.ParamByName('TreatName').AsString := Treatment;
  TreatPriceQuery.Open;
  TreatPrice:= TreatPriceQuery.FieldByName('Cost').AsInteger;
End;
```

I agree with @Remy's content in the comment to your question, as well. You should be passing parameters around instead of using global variables.

```
function TAppointmentForm.GetTreatPrice(const TreatmentName: String): Integer;
Begin
  TreatPriceQuery.SQL.Text:= 'Select Cost from Treatment where TreatName = :TreatName';
  TreatPriceQuery.ParamByName('TreatName').AsString := TreatmentName;
  TreatPriceQuery.Open;
  Result := TreatPriceQuery.FieldByName('Cost').AsInteger;
End;

Procedure TAppointmentForm.GetAppCost;
Var
  Idx: Integer;
begin
  AppCost := 0;
  for Idx := 0 to TreatmentCheckListBox.Items.Count - 1 do
  Begin
    if TreatmentCheckListBox.Checked[Idx] then
    Begin
      AppCost := AppCost + GetTreatPrice(TreatmentCheckListBox.Items[Idx]);
    End;
  End;
end;
```

Comment: And don't forget to initialize `AppCost` before running the loop.

Comment: The code - as listed by the OP - is not vulnerable to SQL injection, due to the use of QuotedStr function.

Comment: @HeartWare: SQL concatenation *is* vulnerable to SQL injection *in general*. While it may not be in this particular use, it's a *horrible* practice that should be educated away from the beginning. I'm not sure why you'd object to starting that education. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I didn't say that it was a bad idea to use SQL parms, but I have been using the QuotedStr principe for many years without any problems, and if you get used to do it that way, it's just as safe as parameters. My comment was merely meant to state that there *are* alternatives to parameters, and they can be just as safe. People have postulated that some code I wrote on SO was vulnerable to SQL injection (using QuotedStr), but every time I have asked them to prove it, they have not been able to do so. For some, "use parameters" have become a mantra, and there's no need to use it in ALL cases.

Comment: @HeartWare: Not using parameters also leads to difficulties with formatting dates, converting numerics, converting logical (boolean) fields, and other issues. IMO it's simply wrong to use SQL concatenation for anything when parameters do it so much more easily and safely. In addition, statements that are run more than once can be compiled and cached by the DB when using parameters, which cannot be done with dynamic SQL. There are far more advantages to using parameters. But this is getting derailed - this question (and my answer) are about "list index out of bounds".

Comment: Strangely enough, I haven't run into those difficulties. Perhaps because - in addition to QuotedStr - I have a DateStr and a BoolStr function in my SQL library that takes care of that... You *do* have a point with the compilation and caching, but in those cases (where an SQL statement is executed a multitude of times), I normally use Stored Procedures instead...

Comment: @HeartWare: Ah, so you've manually written the code to do the work that using parameters does for you automatically, and potentially have to rewrite them if you need to change DBMSs (instead of letting the underlying drivers do it for you automatically), and you also have to concatenate strings every time (and do so multiple times if there are multiple values), making the code both harder to maintain and harder to read. Stored procedures may or may not be appropriate. Manually having to replicate and maintain work that is already done for you for no reason typically is not the proper path.

Comment: That's where we (also) disagree. In my opinion, concatenation is *easier* to read than using parameters (you get to _see_ what the values you are using are, right where they are used, and your eyes don't have to run all over the place to see what the values are), which is the major reason that I use it. Readability is more important to me than following some religious doctrine about using parameters... If parameters allowed me to specify the values "in-place" (like concatenation does), I would conceivably use them, but parameters - to me - lowers the readability...

Comment: @HeartWare: And that's fine for you. I have a good friend who is convinced that he doesn't need to wear a seat belt when he drives his car, because he's been driving for years without one and it's never been an issue; that doesn't prove that everyone doesn't need to wear seatbelts. If you want to post an answer to a question regarding use of parameterized SQL and debate it there, go for it. As I said previously, *this question is about the list index error*, and that's what I answered. Search SO for dozens of discussions on the SQL issue, where you'll find you're in the minority (and why).